# How to setup a 1 way trust, Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory

I am on my home network and connect to workplace via a VPN.

I have a DC on my home network (DC1 , domain = home). How can I setup a 1 way trust, so that I am able to run executables, such as SQL Management Studio using RunAs - then type in credentials for work domain?

First question is, will a 1 way trust solve this, and can I set this up without bothering a network admin at workplace (assuming I have a domain account with enough permissions on work domain)

If yes - any good step by step guide to setup 1 way trust? Server is Windows Server 2008 R2. As mentioned its DC running DNS Role too.

Thanks in advance

Comment: For gods sake please **do** bother a network admin for this one. If anybody even tried this on my network without asking I'd have them sacked.

Comment: @Ben reread the question. I need to setup 1 way trust, my whole point is NOT to change any trust levels on the work domain, only my home domain.

Comment: I did read the question. You don't make it clear if you have authority to do this (your point about asking a network admin makes me think you don't). Bottom line is if you don't have authority (in writing might be a good idea) to do this, **DON'T**.

Comment: @Ben it could be I'm using incorrect terminology which is confusing the issue.

Comment: I apologise if my first comment came on a bit strong. I don't want to get you in trouble, and I also don't want to get your network admin in trouble for allowing you to do this without consent. Like I said, I'd have anybody trying to do this without permission sacked, and I would expect the same for me if it happened to my network.

Comment: Basically what I want to accomplish is run an app as work domain account on this local domain - the app exactly is SQL management studio. All of this workaround is just to get the app to run under this work domain credential. Not sure if this is possible though.

Comment: This is actually a very interesting question and I'll be keeping an eye on this. My own circumstances are that I work for an IT services company and we support several clients, each with their own domain. Due to various policies a lot of these clients do not allow our level 1/2 support staff to RDP to their servers and require them to install the management consoles on their workstations. This is fine for our onsite teams but staff in our management centre have workstations on our domain. We have yet to find a solution to this.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so this is similar to what I've been trying to achieve (as per my comment on your question above) for different reasons. From doing some research on previous ServerFault questions, I've found that the `/netonly` switch for RunAs makes this work.

I've tested this myself. Created a batch file containing:

```
RunAs /netonly /user:Domain\Username mmc.exe
```

Ran it and added the ADUC snappin, connected it to the DC on the remote domain and it works perfectly. What `/netonly` does is to not authenticate using the supplied credentials when the target is launched, but when authenticating remotely. This means the account you supply in the runas command doesn't need to be validated and therefore can be on a remote domain.

No trust relationship required, just a connection to the remote domain.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a trust. Go into your DNS setting on your DC (it *is* your dns server right?) and create a conditional forwarder. You can specify auth infor `DOMAIN\user` etc after you do this.

Now ... you **HAVE cleared this with your admin** right? And it's not against your companies AUP to use home machines to connect to the work network right?

Comment: Correct, no restrictions there policy wise. And yes, its basically just one server which is DC, that I'm using off site for MOSS dev.

Comment: ok, I setup a forwarder to the best of my knowledge, located the work DNS server, but this hasn't solve my issue. When I try RUN AS - select an app, I get this error - The security database on the server does not have a computer account for this workstation trust relationship.

Comment: @MichaelOz what happens when you run `nslookup <work_domain.whatever>`?

Comment: for example <work_domain.hello> - gives me the address of work primary dns, then non auth lookup: <work_domain>.hello.<mydomain> and an address starting with 66.

Comment: can you do `runas /user:DOMAIN\user cmd` ?

Comment: tried that. Anyways thanks for the assistance, but I think I need to read a book on the subject :)

Comment: I think you need to discuss options with your network admin.  Maybe they have a way to allow you to do your work remotely.